# Keras Multiclass Classification (Dense model) - Confusion Matrix Incorrect

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, multiclass-classification

[image][image]I have a labeled dataset. last column (78) contains 4 types of attack. following codes confusion matrix is correct for two types of attack. can any one help to modify the code for keras multiclass attack detection and correction for get correct confusion matrix? and for correct code for precision, FPR,TPR for multiclass. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

dataset_original = pd.read_csv('./XYZ.csv')

# Dron NaN value from Data Frame
dataset = dataset_original.dropna()


# data cleansing
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:78]
print(X.info())
print(type(X))
y = dataset.iloc[:, 78] #78 is labeled column contains 4 anomaly type
print(y)


# encode the labels to 0, 1 respectively
print(y[100:110])
encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = encoder.fit_transform(y)
print([y[100:110]])

# Split the dataset now
XTrain, XTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)


# feature scaling
scalar = StandardScaler()
XTrain = scalar.fit_transform(XTrain)
XTest = scalar.transform(XTest)


# modeling
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=16, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu', input_dim=78))
model.add(Dense(units=8, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=6, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(XTrain, yTrain, batch_size=1000, epochs=10)


history = model.fit(XTrain, yTrain, batch_size=1000, epochs=10, verbose=1, validation_data=(XTest, 
yTest))


yPred = model.predict(XTest)
yPred = [1 if y > 0.5 else 0 for y in yPred]
matrix = confusion_matrix(yTest, yPred)`enter code here`
print(matrix)
accuracy = (matrix[0][0] + matrix[1][1]) / (matrix[0][0] + matrix[0][1] + matrix[1][0] + matrix[1][1])
print("Accuracy: " + str(accuracy * 100) + "%")
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly, you are trying to solve a multiclass classification problem where your target label belongs to 4 different attacks. Therefore, you should use the output Dense layer having 4 units instead of 1 with a 'softmax' activation function (not 'sigmoid' activation). Additionally, you should use 'categorical_crossentropy' loss in place of 'binary_crossentropy' while compiling your model.
Furthermore, with this setting, applying argmax on prediction result (that has 4 class probability values for each test sample) you will get the final label/class.

---

[Edit]
Your confusion matrix and high accuracy indicates that you are working with an imbalanced dataset. May be very high number of samples are from class 0 and few samples are from the remaining 3 classes. To handle this you may want to apply weighting samples or over-sampling/under-sampling approaches.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your response. you are absolutely understanding my expectation. I have followed your advise and i got 1 error regarding confusion matrix matrix = confusion_matrix(yTest, yPred),                                                           ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput targets                                                                                                            can you pls kindly check the error for resolve. thanks

Comment: With this new setting, you don't need to apply threshold on yPred and instead use argmax. Also make sure the shape of yPred and yTest in the confusion_matrix is same.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am new in keras. if you have time, can you pls cooperate to write or modify last few lines to set argmax for confusion matrix?

Comment: Instead of using y = encoder.fit_transform (as i haven't used before) can you try using 
y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=4)

and for confusion_matrix try the followings:
matrix = confusion_matrix(yTest.argmax(axis=1), yPred.argmax(axis=1))

Comment: numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Comment: So the overall changes i would like to apply on:
 y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=4)
model.add(Dense(units=4, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
>> Now train with model.fit
>> Prediction
yPred = model.predict(XTest)
matrix = confusion_matrix(yTest.argmax(axis=1), yPred.argmax(axis=1))

Comment: y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=4)                                   
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'BENIGN'

Comment: Ok, Please try applying y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=4) right after the y = encoder.fit_transform(y) line. I assume your labels are in String format. So fit transform will map the string label to integer and then apply the to_categorical. Now it should work.

Comment: y = encoder.fit_transform(y)
y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=4)...................when i uses both line its working fine but there is no changes of result as like as eariler....because y = encoder.fit_transform(y) for Binary output only BENIGN/ATTACK...so confusion matrix still remain same. as per categorical expectation, any how we have to use only y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=4)

Comment: Can you show the value of y after fit_transform(y) and to_categorical(....)?
would you please share your csv file?

Comment: Are you sure that your dataset contains 4 types of attack? How is the distributions of 4 different labels?
And have you commented out yPred = [1 if y > 0.5 else 0 for y in yPred]?

Comment: BENIGN
Web Attack ・ｿｽ Brute Force
Web Attack ・ｿｽ Sql Injection
Web Attack ・ｿｽ XSS                                                                                                 yes i have commented yPred....

Comment: Would you please try using 
matrix = confusion_matrix(yTest.argmax(axis=1), yPred.argmax(axis=1), labels=[0, 1, 2, 3])

Comment: Pls see enclosed matrix. here i had uses both y = encoder.fit_transform(y)
y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=4) otherwise get error if uses only categorical. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'BENIGN'....and matrix all results are in a column...

Comment: Your confusion matrix and high accuracy indicates a imbalanced dataset. May be very high number of samples are from class 0 and few samples are from the remaining 3 classes. To handle this you can use weighting samples or over-sampling/under-sampling approaches. Please check those terms and how can you use.

Comment: you are right, high numbers of sample at class 0. and thanks for your advise.